# How can I count existing and non-existing values with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I am new to MySQL.

I have a table with answer ids.
Answers can look like this:`a1, a2, a3 ...`, but due to some problems some are `NULL`, some are blank, and some are others like `1 a` etc.

Now I want to calculate the count of ids with `a1 a2 a3` distinctly. But how is it possible to do this leaving others like `NULL`, blanks and garbage.

The output should look like this

```
atype count 
a1      45
a2       0
a3      56
```

If there is no row entry for a particular answer, the count should be 0.

Comment: do you actually need the 0 counts (or can they be missing entirely)?

Comment: If you want to calculate count of id with a1,a2,a3.. Then you can check my answer and demo

Answer (score 3):

## Solution 1: Two queries

You should use a table that contains your desired (correct) answer types:

```
| id | answer |
---------------
| 1  | a1     |
| 2  | a2     |
etc.
```

Then you can count the results that actually exist in your table:

```
SELECT atype, COUNT( * ) cnt FROM answers JOIN mytable 
    ON mytable.atype=answers.answer GROUP BY answers.answer;
```

*(Replace `mytable` with the appropriate table name).*

Of course, this will only return existing results. To count the zero rows, you can look for answers that do not appear in your table:

```
SELECT answer, '0' AS cnt FROM answers WHERE answer NOT IN(
    SELECT DISTINCT answer FROM answers JOIN mytable WHERE answer=mytable.atype );
```

[Here is an example.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac481/3)

## Solution 2: A counter table

Another way would be to use a counter table:

```
| id | answer | cnt |
---------------------
| 1  | a1     | 0   |
| 2  | a2     | 0   |
etc.
```

Then every time you want to count the results, do:

```
UPDATE answers SET cnt=0;

UPDATE answers SET cnt=
    (SELECT cnt FROM 
        ((SELECT answers.answer, COUNT(*) AS cnt 
          FROM answers JOIN mytable ON answers.answer=myTable.aType 
          GROUP BY answers.answer) AS tbl) 
     WHERE answers.answer=tbl.answer) 
WHERE EXISTS 
    (SELECT cnt FROM 
        ((SELECT answers.answer, COUNT(*) AS cnt
          FROM answers JOIN mytable ON answers.answer=mytable.atype
          GROUP BY answers.answer) AS tbl) 
     WHERE answers.answer=tbl.answer);
```

This will update the counter values in your answers table, and you can just `SELECT * FROM answers ORDER BY answer` to get your result.

Be warned, though: I believe the second version, while convenient, will take a lot more computing power than the first one, due to all the subqueries needed.

[Here is this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/374e9/3) (UPDATE statements are on the left side!)

## Solution 3: Update upon write

The best and least performance hungry solution for use cases like yours, in my opinion, is to create a counter table like the one I described in #2, but **update the counter values at the time users are answering the questions**, instead of re-calculating all the entries everytime you want to know the count.

This can easily be done. Everytime a question is answered correctly, increase the counter in the `answers` table:

```
UPDATE answers SET cnt=cnt+1 WHERE answers.answer='a1';
```

And again, your query will be

```
SELECT * FROM answers ORDER BY answer;
```

Comment: +1 for excellent effort and please add a demo link as well. So someone would be convinced to look in your solution in bit detail as it is sufficiently detailed :)

Comment: I added examples for solutions #1 and #2. #3 is self-explanatory, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.atype,count(*) as `Count`
from
 (select 'a1' as atype union all
  select 'a2' as atype union all
  select 'a3' as atype )a
left join <your_table> b
on a.atype =b.atype
group by atype
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to present all major choices, each query is followed by demo link. Link contains description

```
select AType,count(*) as Count from tb2
where atype!='' and atype is not null and atype!='0' group by atype
```

[Link1 (Best One) To count answers of each (existing) type other than balank 0 and null](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d02a/6)

```
select (select count(id) from tb2 where atype='a1') as A1,(select count(id) from
tb2 where atype='a2') as A2,(select count(id) from tb2 where atype='a3') as A3;
```

[Link2 (Simple and most suitable for you) count answers of types  a1,a2 or a3 only (my older method to get similar results to link3)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d02a/2)

```
select AType,count(*) as Count from tb2
where atype in('a1','a2','a3') group by atype
```

[Link3 count answers of types  a1,a2 or a3 only.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d02a/7)

First and last link do not take into account those types which are totally not present in the data. For example, If there is no answer with type a2 then first and third query would tell only number of answers with type a1 and a3 and will not mention answers of atype=a2. However 2nd query does.

Comment: Searching for explicit values (`WHERE atype='a1'`, etc.) will get very tedious, once you have more than a few answers to query.

Comment: Yes @weltraumpirat. You are right to some extent. But I have now changed the trend to be very general which goes in vain may times. Your answer is great (generic), but little tough and I think the jaya's requirement is easily meet-able with a much simpler/shorter solution

Comment: Maybe.  But Stack Overflow is meant to be a knowledge base for others, as well. The answers we give should always be as generic as possible, so that as many people with similar problems as possible may benefit, or - God forbid - learn something ;)

Comment: I agreed @weltraumpirat that answers should be general to be useful for others as well and agreed practically.. But simplicity, short length and clarity comes before generality but after accuracy.

Comment: Well then, to be accurate, you have to take into account correct answers that do not exist in the table (count = 0), as well as ignore incorrect results - which only your last and original statement does. ;)

Comment: Yes old is gold hehehe :)... Well I have covered all possibilities. Link2 is best one. However I know that this user needs only link4. count=0 can not be needed/feasible in open ended number of types. It is feasible just for fixed types. for example three types a1,a2,a3